# An example for a PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\delta(x^1,x^2)$ and $\beta(x^1,x^2)$ be two functions. Is there any example of $\delta$ and $\beta$ which satisfy in the following PDE's?

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x^i}-\frac{\beta}{\delta}\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x^i}=1 \hspace{1cm} for \hspace{1cm}i=1,2
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\delta}\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x^i}=\beta \hspace{1cm} for \hspace{1cm}i=1,2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: make a change of variables $$u=\frac{\beta}{\delta},\quad v=\frac{1}{\delta}.$$

The equation then becomes$$\partial_{x^i} u=v,\quad \partial v_{x^i}=-u,\quad i=1,2.$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Take $\beta (x^1 , x^2 ) = \tan (x^1 +x^2 ) , \delta (x^1 , x^2 ) =\frac{1}{\cos (x^1 +x^2 )} .$